# How can get iframe content

Tags: iframe, download

How can I download content from iframe?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XpZ4.png)

NOT WORKING
document.getElementById('iframeID'); (show "object HTMLIFrameElement" not content)
$(iframeID).contents().find("html").html();

Comment: Check your developer console--look for any warnings about XSS, or the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, or the current values of `document.domain`.

Comment: I tried var txt= $(iframeID).contents().find("html").html(); alert(txt); and now alert is <head></head><body></body>

Comment: Nothing you try (beyond a MitM attack on your own browser) will work, sorry. See the explanation below. 

(This is sometimes a pain in the ass, but if you are trying to access data from an iframe with a source you don't control it's usually for nefarious reasons. If you control the server that serves the iframe, no problem, you just set the appropriate headers to make it promiscuous...and accept the danger to your users).

Comment: Depending on what you try you might get an empty string, a JavaScript exception, or something that looks like an empty page `<head></head><body></body>` but you won't get actual information. 

You can work out how long it took to load the requested page by hooking the `onload` event, which is a form of information leakage, but that's about it.

Answer (score 0):

This will not be possible due to the same-origin policy imposed by the browser. You won't be able to access the contents of that `iframe` unless you are on the same domain.

Some methods will just give you an empty result:

```
document.getElementById('your-wiki-frame').innerHTML
> ""
document.getElementById('your-wiki-frame').innerText
> ""
```

Other methods might explicitly tell you about the restriction:

```
window.frames[0].body
> SecurityError: Permission denied to access property "body" on cross-origin object
```

This might seem like a pain, but if you're just somebody trying to programmatically access the contents of Wikipedia, you have no need for a browser as an intermediary.

If you *really really* wanted to use your browser for these shenanigans, you could route all of your traffic through an HTTP proxy you control so that some special path based off 'en.wikipedia.org' (e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/your-special-page) returns your own site. This way, your browser would accept that the origin of your page was the same as the wikipedia content you are trying to access. Essentially you'd need to perform a man-in-the-middle attack on yourself, and of course it will only work on a network you control, and you'll run into mixed media restrictions if you try to access an iframe served over https from within a page served over http.